# MVC3 ViewModel with multiple LINQ queries, is it making multiple DB calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

If I am creating a viewmodel to pass to a view and my viewmodel is comprised of several
properties from the same object, how should I create the LINQ query?  At the moment I'm doing it like this:

```
TaskEditViewModel viewModel = new TaskEditViewModel
 {
      Task = taskRepository.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id),
      Status = (taskRepository.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id).CompletionDate.ToString() == "") ? "close" : "open",
      Account = taskRepository.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id).Accounts.First()
 };
 return View(viewModel);
```

My taskRepository returns IQueryable, so does this mean I am making 3 seperate db calls?  Should I be making one call and then building the viewmodel from the results?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough to tell you what is right and whether these are multiple calls (guess it also depends on how your repository is constructed). But I would think that `CompletionDate` and `Accounts` are included in your `Task` model (isn't it always in LinqToSql?) so you could expose them as properties in the viewModel instead of setting them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to revisit this on its anniversary.  I think this **would** have been making multiple db calls due to lazy loading, so not very efficient.

As Ingo Vals correctly commented, the `CompletionDate` and `Account` properties are included in my Task model, so I should have just done something like this:

```
Task viewModel = taskRepository.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id)

return View(viewModel);
```

Then in my view I can get the `CompletionDate` and `Account` properties from the view model